# B2C login_hint with ADFS using SAML2 protocol

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

This article https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/Documentation/Domain-and-login-hint%20Tips%20and%20Tricks.pdf explains how to pass the login_hint to an ADFS login page. My TechnicalProfile for the ADFS ClaimsProvider has the InputClaims defined as shown below. (The username contains the user login name from a previous user journey step.)

```
<InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="username" PartnerClaimType="login_hint" />
</InputClaims>
```

Doing the exact same for an AAD Claims provider works just fine, but it does not work for the SAML2 protocol. According to the article it is supposed to work. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Hi. Should be <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="login_hint" DefaultValue="OIDC:LoginHint" />

Comment: {OIDC:LoginHint} will contain the incoming login_hint OIDC parameter....meaning if you send a login hint to B2C then you will do it like this. However, this is not my case....I'm want to send a login_hint to a upstream IdP. Then the PartnerClaimType is "login_hint", right?

Comment: Not even a hardcode value like below works:
<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="username" PartnerClaimType="login_hint" DefaultValue="first.last@adfstest.com" />

Does not seem like MS have implemented the login_hint parameter for the SAML2 protocol. It only seems to work for OpenIdConnect